# Why does my grid are works for footer only?

Tags: html, css, syntax-error, css-grid

Help me by telling why grid area is not working perfectly. I have used it on nav, main and contents too but output is unexpected (attached below). all the elements get arranged below footer and elements are not on there place.

Please help me ......I am a nw coder and learning web development online

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1.5fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav nav" "sidebar main main main" "sidebar content1 content2" "sidebar footer footer footer";
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: aqua;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background: rgb(208, 212, 212);
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#sidebar {
  grid-area: side;
  background: rgb(238, 255, 0);
}

#content1 {
  grid-area: content1;
  background: rgb(81, 255, 0);
}

#content2 {
  grid-area: content2;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <nav id="navbar">Home About us contact us</nav>
  <main>Main</main>
  <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div id="content1">Content 1</div>
  <div id="content2">Content2</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

**output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: is [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/50t1hYlU23qFVZF1?open=lib%2Fscript.js) what you want?

Comment: No...Nd yeah please tell me my mistake...

Comment: compare your value of `grid-template-areas` and the one in the demo i shared.

Comment: Sir/Ma'am I have already compared my code with several online tutorials and so ended up here... please help

Comment: `"sidebar content1 content2"` - you have defined 4 columns but in this part of the value of `grid-template-areas`, you have provided names for 3 columns - fourth one is missing. You can put a period `.` to mark that space as empty: `"sidebar content1 content2 ."`

Comment: Also, inside `#sidebar`, `grid-area: side;` should be `grid-area: sidebar;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [Pawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13408436/pawan-js)'s answer,

1. You have to add the `grid-template` attribute to the `layout` in css.
2. You have specified 3 rows in `grid-template-rows` attribute, but included 4 rows in `grid-template-areas`.
3. (From [Pawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13408436/pawan-js)'s answer) You defined 4 columns but in grid templates areas you used three `sidebar content1 content2`. You can add a period (.), if you want to ignore a column, e.g. `sidebar . content1 content2`.
4. (From [Pawan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13408436/pawan-js)'s answer) You have wrong `grid-area` for sidebar. Just change to `grid-area: sidebar;` in `#sidebar`.

A working solution (JS Fiddle Link): https://jsfiddle.net/hetkxj03/

Comment: Thanks @Rashedul Alam....Finally its working as intended ...but when i am increasing the height of fourth column to 2fr from 1fr, the size of all other rows gets decreased...I am looking forward for your help.

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to change the height of the 4th row? Everything seems to work exactly fine to me. Even increasing the width of the 4th column seems to be okay to me.

Comment: Sorry I meant 4th row...When I am changing its height to 2fr...the rest of the rows collapse ...maybe to their default size

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/Lyt28kw5/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyt28kw5/) this seems to be working fine. Did you check other things in your code?

Comment: https://coderpad.io/X2HWFNR2  This is the final code...Try changing the height of fourth row

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe it picks the lowest fractional value and takes it as a unit. You can read about the fractional units from [here](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit).

Comment: Ok thanks for your help so far....If yoy get solution, please update here

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in this:

1. You defined 4 columns but in grid templates areas you used three "sidebar content1 content2"

Solution:- Add a period. or you can add content1 or content2 that increases their area.

2. Wrong name used for #sidebar. side instead of the sidebar.

Solution:- You can change the area name to the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks .....I will correct these and check if the problem still persists or not

Comment: Thank you for contributing to StackOverflow. Please consider adding the solution code (full or partial) while answering if possible.